# C# shall I aggregate keys to a bigger object for cache

Tags: caching

Recently I am learning how to use cache in C#. Just thinking if, for example, I have 5 items to describe the status of a user and I want to cache the status.

Shall I create five keys for each user, or put these 5 items in a class and cache the class as a whole with one key for a user? Which could be a better practice and what the advantages and disadvantages for each solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how the access pattern is going to be. If your app will regularly only have the user ID and need to get all the status, obviously put them in a class with the user ID as key. But if your app regularly only need one or some of the status, with the key derived from the known status type and user id (eg, the user ID is 234 and status is Boarded, the key is "234Boarded") you can use that approach, but, only if you don't want to use LINQ goodies (such as `var filledSeats = currentPassengers.Select(p=>yourCache[p].Name)`), in that case, use class (or struct)

Comment: Hi Martheen, thank you for your opinion. I am wondering if there will be any performance differences is there are a large number of users.

Comment: Again, what's the access pattern? Access speed to MemoryCache is O(1), so having large number of users doesn't change the speed.